# Continuously auto-refresh some queries if "B1"> "B2", but auto-refresh all queries every 2 minutes

Tags: excel, vba, loops, refresh, powerquery

I would like to program with VBA the autorefreshing in loop of certain queries, for example 3 queries from 20 existing queries when "B1"> "B2", if this inequality condition is not met then the 20 queries will autorefresh every 2 minutes. Any ideas?
The 20 queries in my workbook are currently refreshed every 2 minutes. I need this refresh mode to be interrupted when cell "B1"> cell "B2" in worksheet "Conclusion". Only the queries involved in obtaining the external data that is operated in the aforementioned cells would self-refresh. For example, query 1, query 2 and query 3 are in charge of supplying the values ​​to be operated on in the calculations that result in the cells mentioned above, therefore they would be the only queries that would be refreshed in a loop until said inequality is resolved. stop complying Once this last happens then the 20 queries would be updated every 2 minutes.
I need help in the preparation of the VBA because my knowledge about the hierarchy of the code is outside my knowledge. Please help!

Comment: People keep suggesting `Application.OnTime` whenever you post this, but you seem intent on ignoring the suggestion.  This site is intended to help *you* fix problem with your code, but if you won't try to write some then it might not be the right place for your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to perform both actions on the link:

https://exceloffthegrid.com/auto-refresh-power-query/

Answer (score 0):

in this example I have 3 external Querys (File1, File2, File3) and only 3 internal Querys (Tabelle1, Tabelle2, Tabelle3).

I hope I understand your logic correct.

First you have to check the worksheet_change envent of the "Conclusion" sheet an check if there is a change in Range("B1:B2), and call another sub (in this case "set_refreshPeriod".

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Worksheets("Conclusion").Range("B1:B2")) Is Nothing Then
        set_refreshPeriod
    End If

End Sub
```

The SUB "set_refreshPeriod" checks B1 and B2 and set the 2 Minutes or not (0 Minutes) in the Query-Settings. Also it will refresh the external Querys.

```
Sub set_refreshPeriod()

Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
Dim lngPeriod As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim internalQuerys As Variant 'The 20 Querys which update all 2 Minutes
Dim externalQuerys As Variant 'The 3 Querys which update if B1>B2

Set wks = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Conclusion")
Set rng1 = wks.Range("B1")
Set rng2 = wks.Range("B2")

'The name of your Query always starts wiht "Query - " in english or "Abfrage - " in German
'You can add here more Querys
internalQuerys = Array("Abfrage - Tabelle1", _
                        "Abfrage - Tabelle2", _
                        "Abfrage - Tabelle3")

externalQuerys = Array("Abfrage - File1", _
                        "Abfrage - File2", _
                        "Abfrage - File3")

    'if B1 > B2 then do not refresh the internalQuerys every 2 Minutes else do it
    If rng1 > rng2 Then
        lngPeriod = 0 'do not refresh internalQuerys

        'Refresh the the external Querys
        For i = 0 To UBound(externalQuerys)
            ThisWorkbook.Connections(externalQuerys(i)).OLEDBConnection.Refresh
        Next

    Else: lngPeriod = 2 'Time 2 Minutes for internal Querys
    End If

    'Set the RefreshPeriod for the internal Querys
    For i = 0 To UBound(internalQuerys)
        ThisWorkbook.Connections(internalQuerys(i)).OLEDBConnection.RefreshPeriod = lngPeriod
    Next

End Sub
```

Best regards chris

Comment: Hi Cris, what is the difference between internalQuerys and externalQuerys in terms of content; Why do you name some Tabelle and the other File, perhaps in the first what you represent are all the query tables in the workbook?

Comment: I am currently studying the code that you left me to understand and apply it to my situation that is a little more difficult than the one presented in this post. I would like to know what was asked before and add to my question: The first code I put in the window of the worksheet "Conclusion" and the second code I put immediately below the previous one?

Comment: Hello Perry, I got the names internalQuery and externalQuery because you wrote in your question from internal and external. I understood, that you have 3 Tables (external - File) That should be updated if B1>B2 and the others 20 (internal - Tabelle) should be updated every 2 Minutes in B1<B2. Yes you have to place the code as you wrote. File and Tabelle are  names for   the querys, you have to replace this with the names of your querys.

Comment: Cris, I had to make another more specific post about what I want, I think I explain myself better here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61856658/loop-refresh-queries-by-taking-the-resulting-values-of-functions-as-a-switch

Comment: Cris, I already tried the code you sent me and I got the following problems:
- Private Sub Worksheet_Change (ByVal Target As Range) does not work for me because "B1" and "B2" have functions, I have tried to change it to Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate ( ) but so far it highlights me in yellow. Will we have to add any other code?
- I need other ranges like "B1:B2" to control autofreshing of other queries. For example, "B1:B2" controls the refresh of "Query - 1"; "Query - 2"; "Query - 3"; but "C1:C2" controls the refresh of "Query - 4"; "Query - 2"; "Query - 6", etc, etc.

Comment: Hello iPerry, I will Check this new requirements later. Which functions are in B1 and B2? Best regards Chris

Comment: Cris, the "Conclusion" worksheet is the most important sheet of my project since it will give all the results of operations that are calculated in other sheets, therefore, all the cells, including "B1" and " B2 "have functions like = 'Sheet'! A2, as you can see is simply functions that relate cells.

Comment: Cris, I had raised the need to use not only the pair of cells "B1": "B2" and its inequality as a query refresh switch, but also some other pairs, for example "C1": "C2"; "D1": "D2", etc.

Comment: Cris, are u alive, help me bro

Comment: Hello Perry, I will check asap. At the moment I‘m very busy.

Comment: Considering that you are busy, I spent all this time trying to improve my post. For this reason I made a new one, and I even made modifications to the code that you gave me for my project,

Comment: I had to make some adjustments to the pot. Now I think that I can understand better what I want. What you named internalQueries will continue to be all the queries in the workbook, and externalQueries will be the triplet of queries to refresh if the condition I mention is met. The new post related to my problem is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62009266/queries-refreshed-depending-on-functions

Comment: Remember Cris that my new article is in the link. You will see that some things that I requested changed. In addition, I modified some aspects of your code and transformed it to where it could work for me, but as you will read in the article, new conditions are already established. I hope you can help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: New link:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62066980/refresh-certain-queries-if-the-value-of-functions-changes

Comment: cris, I waited for your appearance these two days of weekend, and apparently the subject is no longer to your liking.

Comment: Hello iPerry, in Germany it‘s still „Weekend“ today (Holiday/Whit monday)  so you have a chance, if I understand the new article ;).